# How to let TypeScript autocast from custom type

Tags: typescript

I am building a wrapper for a `ioredis` `transaction`. Per the docs a transaction look like this:

```js
redis
  .multi()
  .set('key1', 'hello')
  .set('key2', 'world')
  .exec()
```

to make it more reusable, I made a wrapper to genereate a transaction. `ValueType` is the default type for values passed to `.set()` and is defined by the library:
`type ValueType = string | Buffer | number | any[]`

```js
const setMultiple = async (items: [string, ValueType][]) => {
   // impl
}
```

Now when I call this function using some string values, TypeScript says the types don't match, when `string` is clearly allowed per `ValueType`:

```js
const commands = [
    ['key1', 'hello'],
    ['key2', 'world'],
];

const result = Redis.setMultiple(commands);
// err: Argument of type 'string[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string, ValueType][]'
```

How can I make TypeScript shut up here since this is clearly allowed. `string` is just wrapped in `ValueType`.
I know I can just force cast `commands` by passing `commands as [string, ValueType][]` but it should automatically understand these are correct values right?

Comment: Because `commands` is determined to be an array which contains string arrays of any length. Not tuples of only two items.

Comment: Well, but it's exactly two right? TypeScript is still just a bit dumb then?

Comment: It's a deliberate design choice. It's far more common that people want to use array types than tuple types, so if you don't say what you want, typescript assumes you want an array. In other words, if typescript hears hoofbeats, it assumes horses, not zebras.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll just let `commands` be a custom (correct) type then. Thanks for your help!